# How to capitalize span elements

Tags: css

I have two `span`'s held in a given element, with no spaces between them. I want to capitalize the first letter contained in each `span`. How would I do this?

In this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9s2f1mrj/) I am using the `text-transform` rule, but as you see it does not work.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Add `display: inline-block`

```
.first, .second {
    text-transform: capitalize; 
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Link to fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9s2f1mrj/2/

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Praveen initially suggested it cannot be done with CSS, of which multiple people up voted his answer even though it was factually incorrect.

Comment: @seemly Yeah, finally I found out it was possible. Mistakes happen dude.

Comment: Of course I am aware that mistakes happen, it was more that your answer was generally marked as a vote of confidence by 6 people when your answer stated it can't be done using CSS. This isn't a criticism of you, it's just that this answer was the first "correct" answer, of which you updated your answer from.

Comment: @seemly I have voted up this answer as well buddy... Yes, mistakes happen. I learnt something new as well. I know you aren't rude, but surely you got pissed off, for no fault of mine, right?

Comment: Nah, I wasn't pissed off. It's just wrong that others had voted the answer without researching the facts. =)

Answer (score 10):

The `text-transform` looks for spaces. Since you don't have a space character, it will not capitalise the first character, even though it is in a new tag. The reason being, the `textContent` of both the tags together, do not give two words, but one.

As a workaround to trick the browser, setting the `span` to `inline-block`, will trigger it to be considered as two words:

```
.first, .second {display: inline-block;}
```

The above works.

```css
.first, .second {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<span class="first">first</span><span class="second">second</span>
```

Comment: This answer got 6 up votes when it initially stated that it cannot be done with CSS. That's not true. Adding display: inline-block; is not a hack, it's a work-around.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but when I first saw this before your edit I was bummed that it was not possible with CSS then saw the other answers.

Comment: @MichaelRader I wholeheartedly agree with you mate... `:D` But you can't deny the fact that I gave you a good explanation? `:D`

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick for you.

```
.first, .second {
    display: inline-block;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

I hope it helps !!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more solution using pseudo `::first-letter`. However

> `::first-letter` pseudo-element has an effect only on elements with a display value of *block*, *inline-block*, *table-cell*, *list-item* or *table-caption*. In all other cases, `::first-letter` has no effect.

So my suggestion is:

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
}
span::first-letter {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<span class="first">first</span><span class="second">second</span>
```